# git - how to merge only specific files

Tags: git

I have three commit ids, `commit1`, `commit2` and `commit3`.

`commit3` is a commit in our repo, while the other two are commits in upstream - the `commit1` is the old stable release, and the `commit2` is a new stable.

I'm trying to get a list of files that we changed since the old stable upstream merge and then merge these files to the new stable release (`commit2`).

The first part is easy, `git diff --name-only` excluding a list of folders we never touch; let's say I get a list of 100 files.

Now I'm merging our commit to the new release - merge `commit3` to `commit2`. At this point there are 1000 files affected by this merge, but I know it should be only 100 files, so, theoretically, I can revert the changes on the files that are not in the initial list of 100 files I got with `git diff`.

What is the best way to reset them? I can run `git ls-files` to get all files in repo and then I iterate over this list, checking that the file NOT in the list of 100 affected files retrieved previously, and `git reset --hard -- <filespec>`.

I also tried `git checkout commit2 <filespec>`. In both cases I somehow left with, lets say, 500 affected files, but I expect to be with only 100 files or less. What I'm doing wrong? What is the right way to discard any change made by the merge to all files excluding the 100?

EDIT001:
It may be a good idea to add some code to show how I'm trying to solve the aforementioned problem

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys


def execute_git_command(*args):
    arguments = ['git']
    for arg in args:
        arguments.append(arg)

    git_command = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    git_stdout, git_stderr = git_command.communicate()
    if git_command.returncode != 0:
        sys.stderr.write(
            'Git command "{0}" failed with code {2}. Reason: {1}'.format(' '.join(arguments), git_stderr.decode(),
                                                                         git_command.returncode))
        exit()
    return git_stdout.decode()


def just_execute_git_command(*args):
    arguments = ['git']
    for arg in args:
        arguments.append(arg)

    git_command = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    git_stdout, git_stderr = git_command.communicate()
    return git_stdout.decode()


if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage: {0} previous_upstream_commit new_upstream_commit our_commit_for_merge".format(sys.argv[0]))
    exit()

old_upstream_commit = sys.argv[1]
new_upstream_commit = sys.argv[2]
our_commit_to_merge = sys.argv[3]
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE

print("Trying to merge commit id {0} to {1}".format(our_commit_to_merge, new_upstream_commit))

changed_by_us = execute_git_command('diff',
                                    '--name-only',
                                    old_upstream_commit + ".." + our_commit_to_merge,
                                    '--',
                                    './',
                                    ':(exclude)./some/folders/to/exclude/*')

affected_files = set()
for line in changed_by_us.splitlines():
    affected_files.add(line)
print("{0} files affected by our changes".format(len(affected_files)))

print("Checkingout commit id " + new_upstream_commit)
execute_git_command('checkout', new_upstream_commit)
execute_git_command('submodule', 'sync', '--recursive')
execute_git_command('submodule', 'update', '--init', '--recursive')

print("Creating new branch for it upstream_merge_" + new_upstream_commit)
just_execute_git_command('checkout', '-b', "upstream_merge_" + new_upstream_commit)
just_execute_git_command('merge', our_commit_to_merge)

gitBranch = execute_git_command('branch', '--show-current')
print("Commit {0} merged to branch {1}".format(our_commit_to_merge, gitBranch))

mergeAffectedFiles = execute_git_command('ls-files')

if len(mergeAffectedFiles.splitlines()) > 0:
    print("Will checkout files not affected by ours changes in upstream favor")

    for full_path in mergeAffectedFiles.splitlines():
        # print(conflictingFile)
        # full_path = conflictingFile
        # filename = os.path.basename(full_path)
        if full_path not in affected_files:
            just_execute_git_command('reset', '--hard', '--', full_path)

    mergeAffectedFiles = execute_git_command('ls-files', '--unmerged')

print("{0} conflicting files left for manual resolution.".format(len(mergeAffectedFiles.splitlines())))
```

Disclaimer, I'm not familiar with python :)

EDIT002:
Second thoughts, what if I compose a fake commit of all these 100 files and then cherry-pich it to the new stable release (commit2). Is it technically possible?

Comment: The right way to discard those changes is to do what you did, go through them file by file or folder by folder or some other way, and check out the right version you want to keep. A better question would be how the branch ended up with so many changes if that was unintended. Do you commit build output, like bin folders and whatnot to your repository?

Comment: Also, understand that you're not merging files, that is a byproduct of merging branches, you're *merging branches*. If you discard the changes the source branch introduces for a bunch of files, the branch will still be considered merged, and those files will not turn up as changes any more. From gits perspective you're effectively vetoing those changes away and that's it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen no, it is upstream issue, somehow they twist the git history that way that even merging newer LTS to older one (without any changes on our side) results in thousands of conflicts, I actually wondering what have to be done to poor git to get to this point

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but how to remove all those changes properly? when I reset/checkout file existing in commit2 I guess it will work as expected, but what happens when "new" files were introduced into commit2 from commit3?

Comment: Why do you mention commit1 so often in the question if, apparently, it has nothing to do with it?

Comment: it mentioned exactly two times?

Comment: You will have to delete any files that were added in your branch but that you don't want to bring with you through the merge.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen already do it in exclude list, I think it is easier to add it later manually, but it is a bad solution - gonna loose all history on these files

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is : from `commit3`, build a new branch, which contains only the changes you want to integrate to `commit2`.

This suggestion goes in the same direction as @LasseVKarlsen's comment :

> you're not merging files, that is a byproduct of merging branches, you're merging branches.

It is a way to build a branch with the content you want to merge, and merge that branch.

This branch would fork off `commit2` at the same point as `commit3` : `git merge-base commit2 commit3`

---

Here is an outline of how to do this :

```bash
# 1. from commit3, create a branch 'wip3' :
git checkout -b wip3 commit3

# 2. reset that branch to the merge base :
git reset --soft $(git merge-base commit2 commit3)

# now all modifications are stored in the index :
# 3. discard all the modifications you do not want to keep

# by hand :
git reset that/directory
git reset that/other/directory
git reset that/file
...

# or using the list you got from `git diff commit1 commit3` :
git diff --cached --name-only | grep -v -f filelist.txt | xargs git reset

# 4. create a commit on branch wip3 :
git commit

# 5. you can now merge wip3 into commit2 :
git checkout commit2
git merge wip3
```

*note* : you can run steps `3. 4.` several times : while on branch `wip3`, you can always revert or reapply modifications on some files and `commit --amend`.

Comment: looks promising, gonna check it

Comment: Alas! The git history is so messed up here that I have no other option than resort to fully manual merge. I'll check it on next upstream merge which should be more neat after this manual merge. Will update.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg: you seem to have an issue with the remote repo's history, can you perhaps describe this issue in a separate question ?

Comment: They have an issue with their repo history :). I can, but I dont know the reason for the mess going there. I spoke to guys there, looks like they do things right, each LTS has cherry-picks of backported fixes, but in the end you cant take one LTS and merge it to another without getting, like, 5k files changed/conflicted. But if you really want to take a look at it and explain us how it could be possible to wreak such a havok on git, I'll be glad to provide you with this example. Shall we?

Comment: sure, if you can share the information, there's probably other people that can help too :)

Comment: With pleasure. Will post link here once it is ready

Comment: Here you go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717289/git-whats-wrong-with-git-history-in-this-project-and-how-to-upstream-merge-wit I have a feeling I gonna get tons of downvotes now :)