# git - whats wrong with git history in this project and how to upstream merge with it

Tags: git

This is followup question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701154/git-how-to-merge-only-specific-files/65704427) one. We are trying to do upstream merges with stable releases of [this project](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse). According to developers of it, they create stable branches from master and then cherry-pick ongoing fixes into the stable. Sounds reasonable strategy, however each time we try to merge with newer stable release it is proven to be a nightmare taking weeks to accomplish. Aside our changes we do on top of current stable branch we are using, even merge between two clean stable vanilla branches result in thousands of "modified" files and hundreds if not thousands of conflicts. We tried two approaches, merge newer stable into our branch, and add our changes only to newer stable release. In both cases the result is the same hundreds of conflicting files.
Example:

Lets checkout one of stable branches (20.4.4.18) from the repo
`git checkout -b wip001 1a1becf0`
Now lets pretend we did some changes (in fact the repo is unchanged) and after some time we want to get latest stable (20.12.5.14) into our `wip001` branch
`git merge 32fd4a54`
We got a changelist of over 9k files, and 156 unresolved conflicts. How come that with zero changes to the old stable there is so much changes? Are they completely messing up the git history? How? What would be the right approach to work with such a repo? We cant merge newer stables into our code since it ends up with conflicts like "ours - modified, theirs - deleted", when the file nor modified, neither deleted in both branches. So I'm thinking about replaying our changes each time on top of the new stable we choose as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701154/git-how-to-merge-only-specific-files/65704427).Not sure it would work as intended.

Any help/thoughts is appreciated.

Comment: At a glance, `1a1becf0` isn't an ancestor of `32fd4a54`, so a fast forward isn't possible. Have you considered rebasing your own changes from one branch to the other? Otherwise the best I can think of is creating a fake merge via `git commit-tree` (i.e. a commit with the newer commit's tree, with both of them as parents, oldest first), then merging that to your own branch. I'd be the first to admit that doing this would be rather strange, though (and I'm not sure if it's actually helpful). A rebase is probably saner.

Comment: The problem isn't on your end so much as it is on theirs: cherry-picking means that their repository doesn't record sensible history, making later merging difficult.

Comment: @Hasturkun rebase is more sane but definitely more complicated, even more than the merge, it results in tons of changes and conflicts, actually resolving all merge problems proved to be faster than rebasing. as of commit-tree, it sounds very hackish :) isnt this history messed enough to add some new mess? :)

Comment: @torek, in your opinion, what approach would be used to easy on merge? Not sure I can think of something more appropriate in case of backporting fixes than cherry-picking

Comment: See [Raymond Chen's series of articles about merging instead of cherry-picking](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325).

Comment: For a rebase, I think git should be able to deal with most of it if you're using `--onto` and also passing the previous stable commit as the upstream (as you should only have to deal with your own changes conflicting. Having `git rerere` enabled also helps somewhat). The commit-tree thing is hacky, but does have the benefits of not being a rebase (which tend to be uncomfortable if you aren't the only participant), and creating a link between the stable branch commits.